# Storyboard and View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, uitabbar, uistoryboard

I've created an app with Xcode but I've a problem with a View Controller. In my project file I have a photogallery with the ".xib" extension, I've moved it into the storyboard because I need a tab-based application, but when I run for testing my project I can see only the View Controller, without the tab bar and the other items. Why can't I see my storyboard? I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you still have a reference to your "Main Interface" in your App-Settings. Click on the XCode project - Summary - iPhone / iPod Deployment Info.

Unter "Main Storyboard" you should have a reference to your storyboard. E.g.: `MainStoryboard`

Make sure that "Main Interface" remains empty.

Comment: Thank you, but I've already checked this setting and it's ok, so the problem must be another. Other suggestions?

Comment: Is your ViewController connected to the Tab Bar Controller?

Comment: Yes, it is the first item of the bar.

Comment: When you click on the connection of those two, what does it say?

Comment: What about the entry point of your app? Where does the arrow point to? On the view controller?

Comment: The arrow point is on the "Tab Bar Controller". From there, other two arrows go to "ViewController" (Item 1, that is the Photo Gallery) and to "Second View Controller" (Item 2, still empty).

Comment: P.S. I've tried to move the arrow to the other View Controllers, but nothing changes. It's like if the storyboard doesn't exist.

Comment: Checkout this tutorial and try to debug it: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem was another: there were some lines of code that prevented the storyboard to run. By removing those lines (in "AppDelegate.m"), I've solved my problem. Thank you anyway! :D